# C#: Remove Events from ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I've a ObserableCollection with Items in it, which implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface.
This is how I create it:

```
        var myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
        myCollection.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
```

_

```
        private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                {
                    foreach (ViewModelBase item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged -= myViewModelPropertyChanged;
                    }
                }
                else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                {
                    foreach (ViewModelBase item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        item.PropertyChanged += myViewModelPropertyChanged;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now my question is, doI need to loop trough all items and remove the "myViewModelPropertyChanged" before doing another

```
myCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
```

or does this happen automatically? What about a 
    myCollection.Clear();

Thanks for any input.

Cheers
Joseph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
you have a Collection of objects. For each object, you have subscribed to some member events. Now your object has a reference to your handler functions.

When you clear the collection, if no one else references the member objects, you don't need to unsubscribe explicitly. The objects will get garbage collected.
*The problem occurs when the publisher outlives the subscriber, in which case it keeps the subscriber alive due to the event handler/delegate references*. e.g. if you store the publisher in a static field, if you don't unsubscribe explicitly - the subscriber will not be collected by the GC.

See also: [1198076](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198076/c-explicitly-removing-event-handlers) and other related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a myCollection.Clear(); or create a new myCollection over the old one won't unlink the objects of your collection of the event, and then I would do the iteration