# What's the benefit of using a weak reference in .NET?

Tags: c#, weak-references

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weak references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310685/weak-references)

I understand the concept of a weak reference, but I am unable to find where I should use a weak reference in C#.

Comment: To keep track of when an objects is garbage collected. As for when you'd want to do that, maybe for in-application profiling or something.

Comment: In general, if you don't know when to use a `WeakReference` you should probably avoid it.  It's a way for you to hold onto a reference to an object, but not prevent it from being collected if you are the last remaining reference and it needs the space.

Comment: See [Weak References (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx) for an example of their use beyond tracking GCs.

Answer (score 4):

A good example of where to use a WeakReference would be when implementing the [EventAggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) pattern.

Say you have the code

```
eventAggregator.Subscribe<AnEventType>(this.DoSomethingDelegate);
```

then you will specifically ahve to unsubscribe later if you don't want to have a potential memory leak. See [Explicitly Removing Event Handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198076/c-sharp-explicitly-removing-event-handlers) for more info.

If however the internals of the EventAggregator hold on to the DoSomethingDelegate using a weak reference, then no unsubscription is necessary.

For further learning, I suggest taking a look at the implementation of [EventAggregator in the Microsoft Practices library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx). This internally uses a WeakReferenceDelegate type which wraps a Weakdelegate and allows subscription without explicit unsubscription and no chance of a memory leak.

Best regards,